# how to fix art ascii , i tap one letter is fine, but type a phase the art come out wrong

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, ascii

I need help is this script to convert art ascii

if I type each letter separately, everything is fine, they come out as they should
but, if I try to type a phrase, or more than one letter, the art is all wrong

```
#define BUFF_SIZE 256
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void print(char* string) {
    int len = strlen(string);
    int ind, ctr;
    char ptr;
    for(ind = 0; ind < 3; ++ind) {
        for(ctr = 0; ctr < len; ++ctr) {
            ptr = string[ctr];
            switch(ptr) {
            case 'A':
                switch(ind) {
                case 0:
                    printf(" /\\ ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("/~~\\ ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("      ");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 'B':
                switch(ind) {
                case 0:
                    printf(" __ ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("|__)");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("|__)");
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 'C':
                switch(ind) {
                case 0:
                    printf(" __ ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("/  ` ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("\\__, ");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 'D':
                switch(ind) {
                case 0:
                    printf(" __  ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("|  \\ ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("|__/ ");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 'E':
                switch(ind) {
                case 0:
                    printf(" ___ ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("|__  ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("|___ ");
                    break; 

                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 'F':
                switch(ind) {
                case 0:
                    printf(" ___ ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("|__  ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("|    ");
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 'G':
                switch(ind) {
                case 0:
                    printf(" __   ");
                    break; 
                case 1:
                    printf("/ _`  ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("\\__> ");
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 'H':
                switch(ind) {
                case 0:
                    printf("|__| ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("|  | ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("     ");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 'I':
                switch(ind) {
                case 0:
                    printf(" | ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf(" | ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("   ");
                    break;  
                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 'J':
                switch(ind) {
                case 0:
                    printf("    | ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("\\__/ ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("      ");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 'K':
                switch(ind) {
                case 0:
                    printf("|__/ ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("|  \\ ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("      ");
                    break; 
                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 'L':
                switch(ind) {
                case 0:
                    printf("|    ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("|___ ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("     ");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 'M':
                switch(ind) {
                case 0:
                    printf("|\\/|");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("|  | ");
                    break;
               case 2:
                    printf("     ");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 'N':
                switch(ind) {
                case 0: 
                    printf("|\\ | ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("| \\| ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("      ");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 'O':
                switch(ind) {
                case 0:
                    printf(" __  ");
                    break; 
                case 1:
                    printf("/  \\ ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("\\__/ ");
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 'P':
                switch(ind) {
                case 0:
                    printf(" __ ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("|__) ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("|    ");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 'Q':
                switch(ind) {
                case 0:
                    printf(" __   ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("/  \\ ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("\\__X ");
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 'R':
                switch(ind) {
                case 0:
                    printf(" __  ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("|__) ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("|  \\ ");
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 'S':
                switch(ind) {
                case 0:
                    printf(" __ ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("/__` ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf(".__/ ");
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 'T':
                switch(ind) {
                case 0:
                    printf(" ___ ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("  | ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("  | ");
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 'U':
                switch(ind) {
                case 0:
                    printf("|  | ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("\\__/ ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("      ");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 'V':
                switch(ind) {
                case 0:
                    printf("\\  / ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf(" \\/  ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("      ");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 'W':
                switch(ind) {
                case 0:
                    printf(" |  |  ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf(" |/\\| ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("       ");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 'X':
                switch(ind) {
                case 0:
                    printf(" \\_/ ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf(" / \\ ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("      ");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 'Y':
                switch(ind) {
                case 0:
                    printf(" \\ / ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("  |  ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("     ");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 'Z':
                switch(ind) {
                case 0:
                    printf("  __  ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("  /  ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("  /_  ");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
void print(char* string);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc > 1) {

        char text[BUFF_SIZE] = {0};

        int n = 1;
        while (n < argc) {
            strcat(text, argv[n]);
            strcat(text, " ");
            n++;
        }

        n = 0;
        char ptr;
        while(text[n]) {
            ptr = text[n];
            text[n] = (toupper(ptr));
            n++;
        }

        print(text);

    } else {
        printf("\n Digite o texto a ser convertido \n");
        char text[BUFF_SIZE];
        fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin);
        int i = 0;
        char ptr;
        while(text[i]) {
            ptr = text[i];
            text[i] = (toupper(ptr));
            ++i;
        }
        print(text);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

I need help is this script to convert art ascii

if I type each letter separately, everything is fine, they come out as they should
but, if I try to type a phrase, or more than one letter, the art is all wrong
gostaria de ajuda para tentar arrumar este erro que esta acontecendo

Comment: Assuming ASCII encoding, your code could be *much* smaller if you put all the *"ASCII art" pieces in an array, like e.g. `const char *art[26][3] = { { /* art for A */ }, { /* art for B */ }, ... };` Then you could simply use `printf(arg[ptr - 'A'][ind]);`

Comment: Try having all of your `printf`'s print the exact same amount of characters per letter ! (ie. append spaces at the end as needed). Right now, eg., the letter 'A' prints 4, 5 and 6 respectively for each of the scan lines. That will cause alignment issues.

Comment: Similarly, you'll have to fix vertical alignment between the different letters. Right now, eg., 'A' followed by 'B' will look weird (since the former uses only the top 2 scan lines, and the latter only really the bottom 2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two kinds of alignment issues :

### horizontal alignment

For example, the letter 'A' prints 4, 5 and 6 characters respectively for each of the 3 scan lines. This will cause the next character to come out garbled :

```
 /\  __ 
/~~\ |__)
      |__)
```

To fix that, print the exact same amount of characters for each of the letters by appending spaces at the end of each `printf` as needed.

Eg. for the letter 'A', print 6 characters each :

```
        case 'A':
            switch(ind) {
            case 0:
                printf(" /\\   ");   /* <--- added 2 spaces */
                break;
            case 1:
                printf("/~~\\  ");   /* <--- added 1 space */
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("      ");
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            break;
```

Do the same for all characters.

### vertical alignment

For example, 'A' followed by 'B' will look weird, since for the former only the top 2 scan lines are used, while for the latter only really the bottom 2 :

```
 /\    __ 
/~~\  |__)
      |__)
```

To fix that, choose a vertical alignment base (eg. the bottom scan line), and start all your letters there.

Eg. for the letter 'A', use the bottom 2 scan lines instead of the top 2 :

```
        case 'A':
            switch(ind) {
            case 0:
                printf("      ");    /* <--- moved from case 2 */
                break;
            case 1:
                printf(" /\\   ");   /* <--- moved from case 0 */
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("/~~\\  ");   /* <--- moved from case 1 */
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            break;
```

Resulting in :

```
       __ 
 /\   |__)
/~~\  |__)
```

Do the same for all characters.

Answer (score 1):

*In this situation* you would be well advised to play with your code formatting a little.  It's one of those times where some creative layout will make the code clearer and help you spot some of the bugs @SanderDeDycker has already highlighted:

```
        case 'A': switch(ind) {
            case 0: printf("      "); break;
            case 1: printf(" /\\  "); break;
            case 2: printf("/~~\\ "); break;
        } break;
        case 'B': switch(ind) {
            case 0: printf(" __  "); break;
            case 1: printf("|__) "); break;
            case 2: printf("|__) "); break;
        } break;
        ...
```

You might also consider handling lower-case letters in the same switch:

```
...
   case 'A': case 'a':    // catch upper- and lower-case 'A'
...
```

Comment: Sander De Dycker, Edd Inglis thank you very much for the help, I am fixing the code soon after I put it fixed

Comment: @LeonardoDantas, happy to help.  Don't forget to upvote anything you found helpful and to mark Sander's answer as accepted.